# In search of Regular Expression to return substring of Phone number

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex

I've looking looking at this with no success so far.  I need a regular expression that returns me the string after the one in a phone number.  Let me give you the perfect example:

phone number (in exact format i need): 15063217711

return i need: 5063217711    --> so the FIRST char if its a 1 is removed.  I need a regular expression that matches a 1  only at the BEGINNING of the string and then returns the rest of the phone number.

By the way im using objective C but it should not make much difference.

Comment: ^[0-1](\d+)   this might work and then i can get the 2nd group using an objective c NSRegularExpression but still researching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use positive lookbehind to skip digit 1: `(?<=^1)\d+$`

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for a regular expression.

Just test if the first character in the string is a `1` and if so, take the substring of the rest.

Check out [`[NSString characterAtIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a) and [`[NSString substringFromIndex:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringFromIndex%3a)

Comment: this works in concert with an NSPredicate i have ..i need a regular Expression.

Comment: Understood. I will leave this answer though as it may help a future reader.